# Create mappings that only apply to diff mode

Tags: key-bindings, vimdiff

In my vimrc I have `<C-H>`, `<C-J>`, `<C-K>` and `<C-L>` mapped to navigate between split windows in normal mode.  When I use diff mode I only ever have windows in vertical splits, so I'd like to re-purpose `<C-J>` and `<C-K>` to jump to the previous/next diff.

`:help diff` mentions `&diff` when using vimdiff to determine whether you are in diff mode.  It looks like this also gets set when you start a diff from an existing vim session, so I assume I should leverage this somehow to re-set the mappings, but I'm not exactly sure how.  Based on my 2 second test just before posting this, I tried checking `&diff` in my vimrc and performing the mapping as needed, but as I suspected the vimrc doesn't get read in again when going into diff mode from an existing vim session.

What would be the best way to detect going to/from diff mode and re-setting the mappings accordingly?

Comment: looking for a similar thing but when using fugitive

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create an expression mapping that checks `&diff`. This is done using the `<expr>` keyword.

#### Example

```
nnoremap <expr> <C-J> &diff ? ']c' : '<C-W>j'
```

With this, each time you type `<C-J>`, the expression `&diff ? ']c' : '<C-W>h'` is evaluated, and the result (a string) is used for your map. So, in diff-mode, `<C-J>` will be like `]c` (jump to start of next change); otherwise, it will be like `<C-W>j` (move to window below).

Comment: Would the `&diff` flag only be detected if vim starts in diff mode, say `vim -d ...` or also if you open a buffer in diff mode from within Vim already (say `:diffthis` or equivalent)?

Comment: @gented, I think this command, as it stands, operates at the moment it is run, and never again (unless you reaload the source file where the command is). Probably this is a command you would put in a more complex logic, if you want it to behave dynamically.

Comment: The `<expr>` modifier makes it so that the expression is evaluated every time the mapping is invoked. The result of the expression is a string, which is interpreted as keystrokes.

Answer (score 3):

I use this feature to change the highligting during diffs.

```
if &diff

    " Your setting you want to set when using diff mode.
    "

endif
```

Comment: You can execute this block regardless of the value of `&diff`. The `Diff*` syntax groups are only used for diff. Furthermore, there's no guarantee that this will be re-evaluated when diff mode is entered interactively.

Comment: @tommcdo: I removed the example stuff. But the re-evaluation stuff I was unaware of (mainly because I don't switch modes, I ether run as vim or as vimdiff).