# Interaction between multiple {event}s and multiple {path}s

Tags: autocmd

From `:h autocmd-events`:

```
You can specify a comma-separated list of event names.  No white space can be
used in this list.  The command applies to all the events in the list.
```

From `:h {pat}`:

```
The {pat} argument can be a comma separated list.  This works as if the
command was given with each pattern separately.  Thus this command:
    :autocmd BufRead *.txt,*.info set et
Is equivalent to:
    :autocmd BufRead *.txt set et
    :autocmd BufRead *.info set et
```

However, it seems that not all events match `{pat}` against the file name: [I've just discovered](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/mapping-specific-for-diff-mode-and-vimdiff), for instance, the existence of `OptionSet`, which matches `{pat}` against an option name.

I'm therefore curious to know how multiple events and multiple patters in a single `autocmd` interact. In other words, I wondering if I can use a single `autocmd` instead of two in the following group:

```
augroup DiffMappings
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * :call SetDiffMappings()
  autocmd OptionSet diff :call SetDiffMappings()
augroup end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very obvious indeed: it works as dumb Cartesian product. In fact, "commas" are there only to save a few keystrokes.

What it means in practice: `autocmd BufEnter,OptionSet *,diff :` is syntactically valid nonsense.

Comment: I was hoping in a component-wise product. Thanks :)